# Can't download ROS-Melodic-Desktop-Full on Ubuntu (No space left on device)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, root, ros

I'm trying to download ROS-Melodic-Desktop-Full on Ubuntu 18.04 using Oracle VM and when I run the command to download it fills up my root drive and runs out of space. I'm new to this and I can't figure it out. I'm following the steps right and I have checked off the right boxes in software and updates too. Am I missing something???
[unable to flush /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i after padding: No space left on device   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy6gL.png) <---- Photo provided here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The full ROS install should be a little over 2Gb; this is not including additional dependencies. If you look at how much storage you've allocated to your VM, it's only ~2.4Gb; thus is actually is filling the hard drive.

You simply need to allocate more storage/provide a larger VHD to your actual virtual machine.

Comment: When I created the VM I gave the virtual size 50GB for the SATA Port 0

Comment: @StevenCornect it may have allocated 50Gb for the whole drive, but there is not 50Gb for the root partition as seen in the screenshot. Perhaps the Ubuntu install was done incorrectly?

Comment: I was able to go along with things after installing ubuntu on side of windows and not on virtual box. I was then able to allocate what I needed. Thanks!